# make array out of string with variable number of spaces in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

This is the code that I would use if it was always single spaces in between words. Since I have multiple spaces in between some words how can my code be changed to remove the extra spaces when using componentsSeparatedBySring. I'm new to OBjective-C so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:
NSString *myString = @"One Two  Three Four    Five";
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];

Answer (score 3):

Use [`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
NSScanner      *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) 
{
    NSString *string;
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charSet intoString:&string];
    [results addObject:string];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSArray *)componentsInString:(NSString *)string withSeparacterInString:(NSString *)separaterStr
{
  if (!string || !separaterStr || [separaterStr length] < 1)
    return [NSArray array];

  NSMutableArray *arr = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:separaterStr]] mutableCopy];

  [arr removeObject:@""]; // removes all empty components

  return arr;
}

NSArray *arr = [Utils componentsInString:@"12 123 \n 14 " withSeparacterInString:@" \n"];
```